# Why set both env.es6=true and parserOptions.ecmaVersion=6 in .eslintrc.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint, eslintrc

I do not understand why I need to specify the same information in two different parameters, 
both  `env: { es6: true }` and `parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: 6 }`.

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6
  },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ecmaVersion` option of `parserOptions` is for syntax. 
The `env` option is for global variables.

If you want to use a Promise for example, `ecmaVersion:latest` is not enough. 
You also have to specify which environment (`env`) to use.

Note that the `env` option automatically enables new syntax. 
But personally, I recommend setting both of them properly.

From [Configure Language Options](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-parser-options) :

> For ES6 syntax, use `{ "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 } }`; for new ES6 global variables, use `{ "env": { "es6": true } }`.
> Setting `{ "env": { "es6": true } }` enables ES6 syntax automatically, but `{ "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 } }` does not enable ES6 globals automatically.

For more information, see [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options).

Answer (score 1):

By this https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-environments it is enough to set just env which automatically set correct `parserOptions.ecmaVersion`. So you should prefer this way to avoid mismatch configuration.

```
es6 - enable all ECMAScript 6 features except for modules (this automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 6).
es2016 - adds all ECMAScript 2016 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 7.
es2017 - adds all ECMAScript 2017 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 8.
es2018 - adds all ECMAScript 2018 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 9.
es2019 - adds all ECMAScript 2019 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 10.
es2020 - adds all ECMAScript 2020 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 11.
es2021 - adds all ECMAScript 2021 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 12.
es2022 - adds all ECMAScript 2022 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 13.
```

UPDATE: There must be an error in ESLint doc because I have tested to add `env.es2016 : true` without `parserOptions.ecmaVersion : 2016` and parser is incorrectly fine with async functions which were added later in es2017. So rather set both env and ecmaVersion.